# Role is not saved when creating new user

Tags: drupal

In one of my drupal sites, the role is not saved to the user, when newly created.
(I can add it afterwards, than it is saved, but not during the creation process).

What could be the reason for this?
(I tried to deactivate several users, role-related modules but nothing helped. The user feed or user import do not work anymore as well).

Answer (score 0):

There's a module for that: [Registration role](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role).

```
Registration role lets an administrator select a role to automatically assign 
to new users. The selected role will be assigned to new registrants.
```

Or you could change the role of the user by implementing [hook_user_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7)

```
function MODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $account->role = 'blogger';
  user_save($account, $edit = array(), $category = 'account');
}
```

Comment: thanks- but I think there is a misunderstanding. I even have this problem when creating a new user as admin myself...normaly there is no need for an additional module for this. in other installations I can create a user and assign a role....Unfortunately in one installation this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1-Try change from MYSql (user role id)
2-Check Your permissions for user roles.

Comment: thanks- but: i can change the role in the drupal frontend..., I can change the role in the db, that is not a problem: my problem is that the role is not saved in the user creation process (logged in as admin )

Answer (score 0):

Think you'll have to share more details on what specific stuff you have on your Drupal install. There's multiple hooks that might be being used to highjack/override the registration process and cause that behaviour.

I would start by checking if any custom module or rule might be causing this in the first place and then if any contrib modules being used affect the registration process. One of these will likely be the culprit.